# Directional PushPin

Tags: windows-phone-7, direction

I have a Windows Phone 7 app using Bing Maps Silverlight control. Can anyone suggest how to place a pushpin on the map indicating direction of travel.

I currently use a red dot to show the current location.

```
<maps:MapLayer x:Name="LocationLayer">
    <maps:Pushpin Style="{StaticResource CurrentLocationPushpinStyle}"  
    Location="{Binding CurrentLocation}"  />
</maps:MapLayer>
```

CurrentLocation is updated on position change event.

What I want to achieve is an arrowhead pointing in the direction of travel (e.Position.Location.Course) which will continuously update as direction of travel changes.

Comment: See here for solution used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571842/rotate-a-style-image-on-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create a custom control which extends `PushPin`.

You could use a RotationTransform to "turn" your arrow based on the current and previous direction. You'll obviously have to track the previous (different) location to do this though.